# reading excel file value goes with comma

Tags: java, excel, formula-editor

```
FormulaEvaluator formulaEval= workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
    CellValue evaluate = formulaEval.evaluate(row.getCell(k));
    cellValue = evaluate.formatAsString();
```

I'm getting an excel value and put this value into the data base. 
but when I put the cellvalue inside of database. 
I want to some value   
name = jake;
but it goes with comma
name = "jake"

how to put some value without comma?

Answer (score 0):

For the simplest version, you can just replace all quotation marks like this:

```
cellValue = evaluate.formatAsString().replaceAll("\"", "");
```

If you need more complex operations (for example if quotation marks inside the String should be allowed), you can use the regex operators ^ (start of line) and $ (end of line).